# Force check for notifications without checking phone

Tags: notifications, oxygenos

When i haven't checked my phone (One Plus 6. Running OxygenOS 10.3.12) for a few hours, when i finally check it it lags like there is no tomorrow.

My guess is that it requests and then receives a crapton of notifications, which causes the lag.

I can take that guess because when i check my phone, nothing is new but after 10-15 seconds it seems to open the floodgates and i receive 20-30 notifications all at once.

Is there a way to tell android to do a check for new notifications every x minutes, even if the phone is left undisturbed?

Comment: What device do you use? The apps that cause those flood of notifications is allowed for background data usage and is it included/excluded from battery optimization?

Comment: One Plus 6. Running OxyenOS 10.3.12

Comment: One Plus is known for extrem battery saving: https://dontkillmyapp.com/oneplus